# Can I just invite someone over to join the beta, or do they need to sign into area51?

Tags: support, beta

Can I just forward the Link to people i want to join the community, or is this really a closed Beta?

Answer (score 7):

Until the beta opens in a week's time, the only people allowed in are people who committed to the proposal on Area 51 before the beta started.